# how to change scroll vertical to horizontal when orientation change?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to change my recycler scroll view vertical to horizontal when the device orientation is change to landscape ...

Here is my code of recyclerView scroll orientation:

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this); 
linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(RecyclerView.VERTICAL); 
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true));
```

Assuming you are using *LinearLayoutManager* in your RecyclerView, then you can pass true as third argument in the [LinearLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#LinearLayoutManager(android.content.Context,%20int,%20boolean)) constructor.

Comment: I think you don't understand my question ..my question is how can i change scroll view orientation according to device orientation.means , if the device is in portrait mode scroll view would be vertical and if the device in landscape mode scroll view orientation would be horizontal....